# Forcing a function to only accept a certain set of data types

Tags: c++, types, sum

is there any way to force functions to only take in vectors of integers (int, unsigned int, uint32_t, etc.) and only those? im trying to write a simple function that returns the sum of all the values with the same return type (since i cant be sure whether or not the value will be greater than (2^32 - 1). however, since `std::vector<T>` doesnt have a `cout` operator for the entire type, i cannot do `sum(vector<vector<T> >)`, since it will return a vector (ignoring the fact that vector + vector doesnt work). i do not wish to overload every type to cout something because i wont be needing it. i just want the function to work when T is some form of an int (and float if possible)

ive tried using `try/except`, but codeblocks catches the operators of the types, so i cant compile if i do a `sum(vector <vector <T> >)`

```
template <typename T>
T sum(std::vector <T> in){
    try{
        T total = 0;
        for(int x = 0; x < in.size(); x++)
            total += in[x];
        return total;
    }
    catch (int e){
        std::cout << "Error " << e << " has occured." << std::endl;
        exit(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: if `T` is an integral type, it is impossible that an `int` is thrown in your code.

Comment: im not familiar with using try/catch yet

Comment: I suggest to never use them then until you know what they're for. As a rule of thumb, the fewer there are in your code, the better.

Comment: Just FYI - if your `sum()` template is instantiated for a type for which `T total = 0` is invalid, then you'll get a compiler error.  The situation is never allowed to linger and manifest at run-time, which is when exceptions and try/catch blocks execute.  C++ doesn't do compilation *at* run-time.  Separately, taking your input vector by `const` reference prevents a temporary copy of the entire container being generated every time the function is called... Gene illustrates this but doesn't explain or justify it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SFINAE to the rescue.

```
#include <type_traits>
//#include <tr1/type_traits> // for C++03, use std::tr1::

template<bool, class T = void>
struct enable_if{};

template<class T>
struct enable_if<true,T>{
  typedef T type;
};

template<class T>
typename enable_if<
    std::is_arithmetic<T>::value,
    T
>::type sum(std::vector <T> in){
    T total = 0;
    for(int x = 0; x < in.size(); x++)
        total += in[x];
    return total;
}
```

Comment: both solutions give me errors with `error: 'enable_if' in namespace 'std' does not name a type`

Comment: @calccrypto Did you include `<type_traits>` as it appears in Xeo's answer? Is your compiler C++0x aware?

Comment: yes. i tried both. i also enabled c++0x and its sending me to crazy places saying that there are errors (probably due to the new rules)

Comment: @calc: Seems TR1 type_traits is lacking `enable_if`, added that in as it's really just a few lines.

Comment: now its giving me errors about ambiguous overloading of operator<< that i overloaded elsewhere that worked fine, before enabling c++0x

Comment: calccrypto: hard to diagnose the C++0x issues without proper details of the code and error message.  Avoiding C++0x, though probably most hassle than it's worth if you're not already using boost, boost also provides a C++03 compatible `enable_if` template and `is_arithmetic<>` etc. tests you could use....

Comment: if you want to enable both integral and floating point you can just use `std::is_arithmetic<T>`

Answer (score 3):

```
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<
    std::is_integral<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::value,
    T>::type
sum(const std::vector<T>& in) { return std::accumulate(in.begin(), in.end(), 0); }
```

Comment: Can't have an `std::vector` of references (not that it makes your code invalid).

Comment: @Luc: correct, after typing those things again and again it became almost automatic :)