# Accepting certain types in constructor

Tags: c++, class, templates, constructor

as a follow up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288193/forcing-a-function-to-only-accept-a-certain-set-of-data-types) question, how can the code be changed so that i can use it in the constructor of a class? im writing a new class where the input needs to be an number of some kind, but nothing else. the code, however, is like declaring the type in front of a function. since constructors dont exactly have types, i need it to not declare a type for the function itself

my new class:

```
class C{
     public:
         C();
         C(T value);// specifically looking for this


         T f(T value); // what the code currently does

};
```

the code in the link creates a function that [accepts and] returns an integer type `T`. i need it to not return anything at all, so that it can be used with a constructor

Comment: It is better you give example in form of some code to let us know what you exactly want to achieve.

Comment: The question is so unclear that it cannot be answered with confidence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to restrict *types* for constructor template. If so, then you can do this:

```
#include <type_traits>
//#include <tr1/type_traits> // for C++03, use std::tr1::

class C
{
  public:

     template<typename T>
     C(T value, typename enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value,T>::type *p=0)
     {

     }
};
```

This constructor template can accept only those `T` for which `is_arithmetic<T>::value` is `true`.  The implementation of `enable_if` is exactly same, as given in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288193/forcing-a-function-to-only-accept-a-certain-set-of-data-types).

---

Alternatively, or if you don't have `type_traits`, then you can use `typelist` along with `enable_if`. I think this is a better solution, as you can specifically define the supported typelist.

```
typedef typelist<int> t1;
typedef typelist<short, t1> t2;
typedef typelist<char, t2> t3;
typedef typelist<unsigned char, t3> t4;
//and so on

typedef t4 supported_types;//supported_types: int, short, char, unsigned char

class C
{
  public:

     template<typename T>
     C(T value, typename enable_if<exits<T,supported_types>::value,T>::type *p=0)
     {

     }
};
```

This constructor template can accept only those `T` for which `exists<T,supported_types>::value` is `true`.  The `exists` metafunction checks whether `T` is existing in the typelist `supported_types` or no. You can add more *types* to this typelist.

And the implementation of `typelist`, and `exists` is here (see my solution):

- [Restrict parameter type in template instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375634/restrict-parameter-type-in-template-instantiation/6375679#6375679)